# PeriodicTimer with TimeProvider assertion is not stable in .NET 8

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0, asp.net-core-8

I have a simple `BackgroundService` in my ASP.NET Core 8 Web API which performs an hourly backup using an `PeriodicTimer`.

Here is the code:

```cs
public class OfflineHourlyDatabaseBackup(
    TimeProvider timeProvider,
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromHours(1), timeProvider);

        while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken) && !stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested) 
        {
            Backup();
        }
    }

    private void Backup()
    {
        using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var offlineDatabaseBackupService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOfflineDatabaseBackupService>();
        offlineDatabaseBackupService.Backup();
    }
}
```

Now I have added unit test to assert the hourly backup behaviour as shown below,

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task OfflineHourlyDatabaseBackup_ExecuteAsync()
{
    // Arrange
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    var mockOfflineDatabaseBackupService = new Mock<IOfflineDatabaseBackupService>();
    serviceCollection.AddSingleton(_ => mockOfflineDatabaseBackupService.Object);
    var timeProvider = new FakeTimeProvider();
    var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

    // Act
    using var offlineHourlyDatabaseBackup = new OfflineHourlyDatabaseBackup(timeProvider, serviceProvider);
    await offlineHourlyDatabaseBackup.StartAsync(default);
    timeProvider.Advance(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
    timeProvider.Advance(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
    await offlineHourlyDatabaseBackup.ExecuteTask!;

    // Assert
    offlineHourlyDatabaseBackup.ExecuteTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully.Should().BeTrue();
    mockOfflineDatabaseBackupService.Verify(x => x.Backup(), Times.AtLeast(2));
}
```

The test assertion is not stable. It passes sometimes and fails sometimes with the following error message

> Moq.MockException :  Expected invocation on the mock at least 2 times,
> but was 1 times: x => x.Backup()

Please can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: No timer is going to run at exactly 2 hours; it's more likely going to run at e.g. 2:00:00.000001 or 1:59:59:999999. If it's the latter case then your test will fail. So advance your fake time provider by slightly more than 2h, e.g. 2h1m, in your test and it should pass.

Comment: No it still doesn't work

Comment: do you think while (await  ... is a correct usage?

Comment: I think so.. I'm curious to know if I'm missing something